# Not receiving task assignment notifications from Lightning

Tags: email-alert, task-notifications

Even after enabling the following permissions, no email notifications are received from Salesforce Lightning, when a task is created(manually) and assigned to user.

1. Setup> Activity Settings> Enable User Control over Task Assignment Notifications
2. User Settings> Activity Reminders> Email me when someone assigns me a task

Does this require an email alert with workflow?

Comment: How are you testing? Are you assigning the task to a different user? It [won't email](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335293&type=1&mode=1) if you're setting the task owner to yourself. Likewise, make sure the org you're testing in has the right email deliverability settings

Comment: That was the issue. I was setting the task owner as myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **task assignment notification will not go out if you're changing the task owner to yourself**. You can go around this by logging in as another user to change the owner to yourself or by changing a test user's email to your own to verify the email is sent.

This scenario is mentioned in this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335293&type=1&mode=1) which also goes over other common scenarios why a task assignment notification might not go out assuming emails are turned on in the org.